# How to make Dashboard and associate two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I will put this *two questions* in the same topic, since there is more people behind questioning the same question.

1. I want to assign `Order` to the `User` and then in **view** of `Orders.index` print the list of all the Orders associated with the User.

**My models:**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
                belongs_to :user


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
               has_many :orders
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
                                  :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Then in View I do:**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= user.order.name %></td>
<tr>
```

I get the undefined method `each` for `nil:NilClass` error. How can I do this in the right way?

Yes, I am a beginner and I was stuck on this a bit too long.

2. I was making a *Dashboard* of the really simple app and I did not get far. *The question:* What is the best approach to make a *Dashboard*? Let's say I would like to put information from more models on it:

   - A list of Orders for Customer
   - An user control in upper right corner (Devise)
   - Some analytics data for each Order

How would you approach doing a Dashboard like that? As usual, all data will be associated with User - when you log-in to the application you see your data.

Comment: how do you collect users list in `@users`? Share your controller precisely action code as well. Also share Popup model code.

Comment: 1. What is `@users` and how are you populating it ? 
2. You are talking about orders in your questions but in your views, your using popups. 
3. User `activeadmin` or `railsadmin` for dashboard sort of thing, they are very handy as far as an admin dashboard is concerned.

Comment: *Ignore previous comment if you saw it, it wasn't quite correct* Why don't you have has_many :orders in the user model? And what is a popup and what does it have to do with anything related to question 1? Also, your popup association is labeled in the plural (it should be .popups). Since it is a `has_many`, you're retrieving an array of `popups`, and calling `.name` on this collection won't work; you'ld have to iterate over the `popups` array and call `.name` on each element.

Comment: Sorry, popups were a spelling mistake. Popup = Order

Comment: @JohnDoeTheOne Ok. So we're going to have to see how the `@users` collected is being created, if the `@users.each` line is where its crashing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you assigning the variables @users to User.all in your controller? Although .all is deprecated, so maybe User.unscoped is better.

   ```
   class YourController < ApplicationController
     def index
       @users = User.unscoped
     end
   end
   ```

Why are you saying has_many :popups and not has_many :orders? It needs to match the name of the other model if you aren't specifying a class specifically. Or if that's another relationship, then you need to add has_many :orders to your user model as well. Then in your view:

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.order.name %></td>
  </tr>
```

2. This is a very generic question. I think you'd do better reading some guides and just giving it a go. Then any specific problems post them on stack.

Comment: Sorry, popups were a spelling mistake. Popup = Order